# How to strip quotes from the script arguments in batch files?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, windows-10, command-prompt

Suppose you're writing a Batch script in which you want to strip the quotes from a string.

If the string is stored in a regular Batch variable, you would do this:

```
set name="John"
echo %name:"=%
```

If the string is stored in a positional parameter, you would do this:

```
echo %~1
```

How would you go about achieving the same effect for script arguments, specifically the `%*` variable? When I try to use the same notation I use for positional paramters, I get this:

```
> echo echo %~* > script.cmd

> script "123" "456"
The following usage of the path operator in batch-parameter
substitution is invalid: %~* 


For valid formats type CALL /? or FOR /?
script was unexpected at this time.
```

How can I make this work? Is there any special syntax for this that I'm not aware of? Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Suppose you're writing a Batch script in which you want to strip the quotes from a string.
>
> If the string is stored in a regular Batch variable, you would do this:
>
> `set name="John"`
> `echo %name:"=%`

Your assertion is incorrect.  A better convention when working with string values is always to `set "variable=value"` with the `"variable=value"` pair quoted, then add quotation marks explicitly when needed upon *retrieval*, rather than upon *assignment*.  For example:

```js
@echo off
setlocal

set "xml=<node>Text</node>"
for /f "tokens=2 delims=<>" %%I in ("%xml%") do echo Text: %%I
```

And thus, the quotation marks are not included in the variable value, but whatever special characters are quoted avoid being interpreted inappropriately.  Even though this isn't really what you're asking, it's still a fundamental convention that's worth practicing.

---

> If the string is stored in a positional parameter, you would do this:
>
> `echo %~1`
>
> How would you go about achieving the same effect for script arguments, specifically the `%*` variable?

True, you can use tilde notation for individual arguments with a numeric index, but not for the `%*` collection.  To solve your riddle, you'd have to iterate through `%*` either with a `for...in` or `shift...goto` loop.  `for...in` is the more efficient choice.  Here's one of a hundred possible paths to a working solution.

```js
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "argv[0]=%~0"
set idx=1

for %%I in (%*) do (
    set "argv[!idx!]=%%~I"
    set /a ubound = idx, idx += 1
)

for /L %%I in (0,1,%ubound%) do echo %%I: !argv[%%I]!

rem // or you could also:
rem // set argv[
```

Comment: I know this is an old post, but what's the correct way to do this when the string contains a carrot `^`? If `val` is `^one two`, `set var="val"` returns `"^one two"` but `set "var=val"` returns `one`.

In my case, I'm trying to read file names with special characters, so I don't believe I can use tokens in my for loop.